# How to run shell commands from Node.Js to linux server after establishing connection using Socket Io. Like running ls -ltr after that cd or mkdir

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, socket.io

I am establishing a good connection with my Linux server. What I want to do now is running some shell commands after I got the connection with the server like doing automation for example cd images after that mkdir newFolder etc.
The main idea of this is to connect to a Linux server from a webpage and when I click some buttons it will establish a connection to that server and some work like restarting Apache or bouncing the application by running a script.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(onRequest);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var SSHClient = require('ssh2').Client;

// Load static files into memory
var staticFiles = {};
var basePath = path.join(require.resolve('xterm'), '..');
staticFiles['/xterm.css'] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(basePath, '../css/xterm.css'));
staticFiles['/xterm.js'] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(basePath, 'xterm.js'));
basePath = path.join(require.resolve('xterm-addon-fit'), '..');
staticFiles['/xterm-addon-fit.js'] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(basePath, 'xterm-addon-fit.js'));
staticFiles['/'] = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

// Handle static file serving
function onRequest(req, res) {
  var file;
  if (req.method === 'GET' && (file = staticFiles[req.url])) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/'
        + (/css$/.test(req.url)
        ? 'css'
        : (/js$/.test(req.url) ? 'javascript' : 'html'))
    });
    return res.end(file);
  }
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.end();
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var conn = new SSHClient();
  conn.on('ready', function() {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION ESTABLISHED ***\r\n');
    conn.shell(function(err, stream) {
      if (err)
        return socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH SHELL ERROR: ' + err.message + ' ***\r\n');
      socket.on('data', function(data) {
        stream.write(data);
      });
      stream.on('data', function(d) {
        socket.emit('data', d.toString('binary'));
      }).on('close', function() {
        conn.end();
      });
    });
  }).on('close', function() {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION CLOSED ***\r\n');
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION ERROR: ' + err.message + ' ***\r\n');
  }).connect({
    host: '192.168.560.1',
    port: 22,
    username: 'USER',
    password: 'anything'

  });
});

let port = 8000;
console.log('Listening on port', port)
server.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute the linux commands on the so created ssh terminal do as below:

Before this snippet:

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
   stream.write(data);
});
```

Add `stream.write('ls');`